# Is it legal to demote an employee for nepotistic reasons?

Tags: demotion, nepotism

My friend was just demoted, she was in charge of a preschool, with about 4-5 caretakers. A close friend of the lady who owns (inherited) the whole business, (including several other locations,) moved back into town a couple weeks ago. She hired her old friend, who should be at the bottom of the pecking order, like any new hire, but was instead put in charge of the preschool. My friend's pay was not docked, however it is a much more stressful position. The children's parents often remarked to the owner about how good my friend was and lovingly ran the house. She ran the house very well.

As for possible reasons for demotion- the preschool is run out of a house and one of the rooms not used for the daycare is rented out to another of the owner's friends. She is a lonely, bitter, 50 year old woman who goes into the preschool after hours and takes pictures of anything not perfectly organized, which is usually like one or two bottles in the sink, or blanket put away bundled up but not folded. My friend constantly works overtime without (the already very little) pay to make sure everything is well cleaned.

When my friend asked why, the owner would not say anything other you will love your new position and the house will be run her way.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I assume you are asking if these actions are legal, but it will be good to make sure.

Comment: In the first place, it is not correct to assume that all new hires are at the bottom of the pecking order. CEOs are often hired from outside and lots of other high level positions. There is nothing wrong or abnormal about that. If this is the US, it was almost certainly legal. The woman could have easily been fired for no stated cause and this person hired.

Comment: A private business can hire anyone they want.  A private business can promote or demote unless there is something in the contract.  VTC as legal question.

Comment: Where did this happen?

Comment: @paparazzo idk - it *is* a legal question, but given the details, the answer is just "yes", so i think it's ok here

Answer (score 5):

So... the new owner moved back into town and decided to put her friend in charge of the business so her firend would run it the way s/he wanted it to be run.

I am not a lawyer, but I don't see where your friend has grounds to sue based on what you've said.  My sympathies to her though.  She can talk to someone in field called "Employment Law" if she's in the US.

It is unclear to me why your friend is in a "more stressful" position now that she isn't in charge of 4-5 other caregivers.  She's no longer responsible for the care that each of them gives because she isn't in charge.  She didn't even lose her "supervisor" pay rate.

The time she used to spend doing "unpaid overtime" should probably be spent looking for a new job where she can be appreciated for her talent.

Best wishes

Comment: I agree.  Its the owner's business and she can run it how she sees fit.  If your friend doesnt like it, she doesnt have to work there.

Comment: On the other hand, hiring an unqualified person into a higher position can become very expensive for a company. You would also think about your loyalty to the company since their loyalty to you is now proven to be exactly zero, and you should think very hard about unpaid overtime. I would also not be very motivated to work hard and more motivated to get my CV out.